# Adverbs, prepositions, nouns, "home", and "about"

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, prepositional-phrases

I'm confused about how the following sentences should be analyzed, in terms of which words are prepositions and adverbs, how the phrases break up, etc.:

1. She was going home.
2. She was home.
3. <strike>She was at home.</strike>
4. She got home.
5. My height is six feet.
6. I am six feet.
7. I am about six feet.
8. He is my height.
9. He is about my height.
10. I saw a man my height yesterday.
11. I saw a man about my height yesterday.

For instance, is it possible that *my height* falls into different categories in #8 and #9?

**EDIT:** Ok, now I have one answer from **Daniel δ** and a some requests for more specific questions.

- I'm most concerned about *home*, *about*, *six feet*, and *my height*.
- Daniel δ says that *home* is an adverb in #1, #2, and #4. I'm assuming this is just a special quirk that happens with *home*?
- I'm not convinced that *my height* is always a noun phrase, or there's something I'm missing. In #8, if *my height* is just a noun phrase, that would mean that *He*, the subject, *is* actually a height, but he's a person, not a height any other form of measurement (Same for *six feet* in #6). Daniel δ suggests that #10 is short for "I saw a man who was my height yesterday", but something seems special about this construction. If *height* is just a noun, then why does switching it for some other noun like *lawyer* fail? We could say "He is a lawyer" but not "I saw a man a lawyer yesterday". But *my height* does make sense as a noun in #9, since we can call *about* a preposition that just takes *my height* as part of a prepositional phrase...
- As **FumbleFingers** noted, #11 can be interpreted in at least two ways. I'm interested in the sense that fits the analogy #8:#9 :: #10:#11.

Comment: That's a lot of work to do, analyzing all your sentences for you. Can you make it easier for us? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: In all cases except the last, *about* unambiguously means *approximately*. But in the last case, if you were for example [the world's talllest man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Wadlow) you might go to see a doctor about your height - but the doctor might actually be average height or even abnormally short.

Comment: ... *about* is usually called a *preposition* because that's just the "bucket category" for little words we all know but can't fit into any of the major categories. It's such a crude naming system it's barely worth bothering with, but in OP's examples I would say it's functioning as an adjective - or [modifier](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/modifier.htm), which I prefer, since it's modifying "my height".

Comment: _About_ is a _[**Quantifier**](http://www.stanford.edu/group/nasslli/courses/peters-wes/PWbookdraft2-3.pdf)_; specifically, it's a [Hedging](http://georgelakoff.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/hedges-a-study-in-meaning-criteria-and-the-logic-of-fuzzy-concepts-journal-of-philosophical-logic-2-lakoff-19731.pdf) quantifier.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'd say *about* is a preposition; basically, a preposition is an adverb that takes a noun object.  In *about my height*, *about* is modifying a noun.

Comment: @Daniel: I thought about that. I suppose you could say my *"about"* there is an adverb/adjective modifying *"that"*. But when I think about it that way, that's not what I mean - I didn't think *approximately "that"*, I thought *exactly* that. In short, I think that *"about"* isn't really an adverb. It's a non-adjectival preposition doing something queer in relation to *"thought"*.

Comment: @John Lawler: Would you still call *about* a "hedging quantifier* in my first sentence above? I suppose it's modifying the verb *thought* there, in that it means I thought for some extended period of time, rather than that the idea briefly entered my consciousness (I didn't actually think deep or long, obviously - it was just for the sake of the example usage).

Comment: @JohnLawler Well, I won't pretend to have read everything you linked (!) or to really know what I'm talking about in the rest of this comment, and I hope I've clarified my question a bit in the edit above ... it seems to me the discussions in your links are about semantics, and I was just wondering how *about* works syntactically.

Comment: There are several words _about_ with different properties. The one we were discussing was the _about_ that modifies quantifiers to warn that they are only close to the real value. The one FF mentions is the preposition _about_ that physically means _close to_ and metaphorically gets used with picture nouns to indicate content (*a story about Trump, an idea about global warming, a book about the Thirty Years' War*). That's either the same word in a different use, or two different words that are pronounced alike and came from the same root. You tell me; I don't care.

Comment: As for semantics vs syntax, you really can't keep them separate in theory. They're useful for concentrating on automatic things, like *a/an* alternation, or Dummy *It*, but most cyclic syntax is controlled (*Governed* is the technical term) by the **meanings** of the predicate in each clause. See the [Verb Class Index](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/levin.verbs2.txt) from Levin 1993.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, JohnJamesSmith, Check out my edit.  I've decided that both *home* and *about* are adverbs.  My reasoning is contained in the edit.

Answer (score 3):

1. **She was going home.**  *[Home](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/home)* is an adverb meaning *to home*, *[she](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/she)* is a pronoun, *[going](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/go)* is a participle, *[was](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/was)* is a copula.
2. **She was home.**  *Home* is an adverb meaning *at home*.
3. **She was at home.**  *Home* is a noun, *[at](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/at)* is a preposition.
4. **She got home.**  *Home* is an adverb.
5. **My height is six feet.**  *[Feet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/foot)* is a noun, *[six](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/six)* is an adjective, *[height](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/height)* is a noun, *[my](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/my)* is a possessive pronoun adjective.
6. **I am six feet.**  *[I](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/I)* is a pronoun, and it is used to mean *my height*.
7. **I am about six feet.**  *[About](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/about)* is an adverb.
8. **He is my height.**  *[He](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/he)* is a pronoun, and it is used to mean *his height*.
9. **He is about my height.** [Explained above]
10. **I saw a man *[who was]* my height yesterday.**  *[Saw](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/see)* is a verb, *[man](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/man)* is a noun, *[yesterday](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yesterday)* is an adverb, *who was* is understood.
11. **I saw a man about my height yesterday.** [Explained above]

    - *Home* is special in that it can be a place (noun) or an adverb, with no variation of form.  Not all nouns operate that way.
    - *My height* in #8 is the same as in #9.  *He is my height* is simply short for (and understood to mean) *His height is my height*.  *My height* is still a noun phrase.  You can understand it as an idiomatic construction; this type of construction does not apply to a wide range of situations (e.g. you wouldn't say *he is my idea*).  It seems to work for personal characteristics such as *height*, *weight*, *color*, and *size*.
    - *About* is an adverb in all your examples but the second interpretation of #11.  The basic difference between an adverb and a preposition is that an adverb modifies the verb (or an adjective or another adverb), while a preposition always modifies a noun (the object of the preposition). A simple test is to remove the word in question from the sentence.  Does the basic structure change?  If not, the word was an adverb.  For instance, in *He fell down*, *down* is an adverb (modifying *fell*).  If you remove it, the sentence becomes *He fell*, which still makes sense.  However, in *He fell down the hill*, *down* is a preposition (modifying *the hill*).  If you remove it, the sentence becomes *He fell the hill*, which does not make sense.  As to your example, *He is about my height*, it appears that *about* does modify a noun (*my height*), so it seems like a preposition.  However, removing the word reveals that *my height* was the **direct object** of the sentence, not the object of the preposition, and that *about* had actually been modifying *is*: *He is my height*.
    - The two interpretations of #11 boil down to the difference between *about* as an adverb and *about* as a preposition; *I saw a man about my height* (*about* is a preposition modifying *height*) and *I saw a man [who was] about my height* (*about* is an adverb, modifying *was*).    It's ambiguous because of the possible ellipsis of *who was*.

Comment: I think this is **about** the level where classifying words (or specific usages thereof) as either *adverb* or *preposition* starts to become pointless. In the case of *seeing a man about your height* it's really overanalysing to suggest *about* is one or the other part of speech depending on whether the speaker (or hearer) imagines it preceded by an elided *"who was"*.

Comment: **About** was an adverb modifying *is* in your comment :)  Seriously, I think it makes *more* sense and becomes *more* clearcut this way; I don't agree that it's pointless.  A part of speech is named according to what it modifies: it's that simple.  I would say that what you described is not a worse case of overanalyzation than determining which possible meaning (i.e. seeing a man concerning your height vs. seeing a man who was approximately as tall as you) is intended by *seeing a man about your height*.

Comment: Anyway, the OP specifically asked about the structures behind each meaning, which gives me a good excuse!

Comment: The distinction between those *concerning* and *approximately the same* meanings does indeed turn on meaningful differences in "parts of speech". All I'm saying is that it becomes meaningless with *"I saw a man [who was] about my height"*. In this case the classification categories and methods of assigning words to roles end up with us toggling the category of the word "about" based purely on exactly how explicitly we perceive "[who was]" to be implied by the construction. IMHO by that point it's a useless distinction.

Answer (score 0):

The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* takes *home* to be a preposition and a noun, but never an adverb. In all your examples, it would be a preposition. Similarly, *about* is always a preposition. The other two, *six feet* and *my height* are both noun phrases.

Part of your problem, I believe, is a confusion between category and function. This kind of confusion is rampant. Even though *six feet* is always an NP, it can perform various functions including: subject (e.g., *six feet is too much*), object (e.g., *His height has reached six feet*), and modifier (e.g., *a six foot point guard*, ok *foot* not *feet*).

In *I saw a man my height*, the NP *my height* functions as a modifier of *man*.

Finally, according to *CGEL*, *yesterday* is a pronoun. In those sentences, it is functioning as an adjunct.

Comment: A preposition always modifies a noun, which *home* does not. *Home* is modifying *got*, which is a verb. *About* also modifies the verb in all the OP's examples, hence it is also an adverb, not a prep. Also, a pronoun is a substitute for a noun, which *yesterday* isn't.  It *is* an adjunct, though; specifically an adverb.  Now I'm curious as to how you make out that *home* and *about* are prepositions and *yesterday* is a pronoun?

Comment: Yes, that's the party line, at least sort of. The NP is usually taken to be the object of the preposition, not the head with the preposition as a modifier. Regardless, there's no good reason for that to be true, and it turns out that it isn't. Consider the OED's entry for *for* sense 19b: *take for granted, leave for dead, for certain,* etc. Also, consider *out from under the bed.* Every dictionary lists *from* as a preposition, but its complement is the PP *under the bed*, not an NP. Jespersen show this almost 100 years ago, but it's not well known.

Comment: The arguments for *home* as a preposition include ability to function as a complement to *be* (prototypical adverbs can't). So you can say *I'm home,* but you can't say *I'm quickly.* Similarly, the verb *head* meaning "set out in a particular direction" takes PP complements and not AdvP complements. So *I'll head home* supports the preposition analysis. Also you can say *I'll come right home* even though *right* commonly modified prepositions, but not adverbs. The only thing arguing against *home* as a preposition is the lack of an object. But I dealt with that in the comment above.

Comment: Yesterday as a pronoun is trickier. First of all, as you say, pronouns "substitute for" nouns (NPs actually). The NP here is the particular day that was yesterday. Today, being Saturday for me, *yesterday* can replace *Friday*. Also, like pronouns, *yesterday* is deictic, that is, it requires contextual information. When I use *you* the meaning depends on who I'm addressing. Similarly, when I use *yesterday* it depends what day it is today. Granted, however, the personal pronouns decline for case while *yesterday* doesn't. Still, it has many characteristics of pronouns.

Comment: Now I'm curious about how would *about* NOT be a preposition.